# Height of binary tree type instantiation is excessive

Tags: typescript

I'm playing around in the type system and I'm currently trying to make a reverse level-order traversal at the type level. These are the types I'm working with:

```
type LEFT = 0;
type VALUE = 1;
type RIGHT = 2;

type List = ReadonlyArray<unknown>;

type Increment<N extends List> = [...N, unknown];
type Decrement<N extends List> = N extends readonly [...infer H, any] ? H : never;

// `Node` already exists as a built-in... so I used Deno...
type Deno = [LEFT: Deno | undefined, VALUE: number, RIGHT: Deno | undefined];
```

I'm using a tuple instead of an object type to represent nodes since it'll be easier to create and change testing values. I also have some aliases to make it more "readable" when accessing the data (`MyDeno[LEFT]` is easier to understand than `MyDeno[0]`). Also, I'm using tuple lengths to represent numbers, since they're *much* easier to work with and don't need a limit to be manually specified.

Anyways, I can get the height of a tree in JavaScript like this:

```
function height(node) {
  if (!node) return 0;

  const lhs = height(node.left);
  const rhs = height(node.right);

  return Math.max(lhs, rhs) + 1;
}
```

But my attempt at transferring this to the type system generates an error:

```
type Max<A extends List, B extends List> = A extends [...B, ...any[]] ? A : B;

type Height<Root extends Deno | undefined> =
    Root extends Deno
        ? Max<Increment<Height<Root[LEFT]>>, Increment<Height<Root[RIGHT]>>>
//            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
        : [];
```

even though it works with the sample data:

```
type Data = [
    [
        [undefined, 4, undefined],
        2,
        [undefined, 5, undefined],
    ],
    1,
    [undefined, 3, undefined],
];

// Should be 3 since the height of `Data` is 3
type T = Height<Data>["length"];
//   ^? 3
```

I wasn't expecting this to throw "Type instantiation is excessively deep"... Where in my type is the fault, and how could I refactor my `Height` type so that it doesn't throw this error? Until I can correct this, I'll stick with using `//@ts-ignore`.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mAreQW)

---

[Completed implementation](https://github.com/kelsny/ja-reverse-level-order-traversal/blob/main/translated.ts) and [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WzP32N)

Comment: Unless you require `Height<T>` to be distributive in unions in `T`, I'd say to [un-distributive-ize it](https://tsplay.dev/m36r3N) since that's easier for the compiler to handle (instead of trying to deal with what might happen if `T` is split into pieces all the way down).  Does that address the question fully or am I missing something?

Comment: @jcalz Oh yeah that totally works. I hadn't thought that distributive types would be a problem here. You can write up an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've noticed that sometimes when [recursive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types) are [distributive](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) there is a greater chance of hitting instantiation depth limits than there is when the type is non-distributive.

Thus, one approach I take is to see if I can proceed by turning off distributivity over unions (via the standard one-tuple-wrapper technique `X extends Y ? A : B` ➝ `[X] extends [Y] ? A : B`):

```
type Height<Root extends Deno | undefined> =
    [Root] extends [Deno]
    ? Max<Increment<Height<Root[LEFT]>>, Increment<Height<Root[RIGHT]>>>  // okay
    : [];
```

That works, at least for your example code.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMgogMQCpQLxQAwG4CwAoUSKANQEEYBVONKARlwPGgCUBJAcQAkV0AmB-IWgwAlgGdgNZhACGAEwD2AOwA2IUgCcNMkAB4ArkoDWShQHclAPgGMirJQGMNEALYQlwXQDkoEAB7A7nJisOLAljQA2gB0sV4ANFCGJuZKALoMQlAAIhBOru6ePv6BSsGhEhHoxQFBIc7yympQMbEiSgBmEBpQnIkySiBpUAD8vVAAXFBKEABu3TZZuaZR8MhTywpQAD5JZRAd7RByiWSUcFNK+i4ARt2JbFxIG+5bu4ZyB0dyGfiCTFAALIyPy6Ui+WplEKiCSJABCENK5Rh4Ro4JKdRasWicMS2IGIEiaWGY3BUzhiwBnAgIgA5gALTzMBQKSQYqE5V47PafQ4zORVfBQYUtZms4bs8qRTZpIUisbA0H2fJuDy6al0xm6MXASJrJBpSyWRLK5yqzwahlMlm6x7cQ1G4UAeidUAURh0cuFUyJlKI2RkwBkUS9LVDIpaHy+-MSABZElG+cc0vFwyLeKm8BGI5FE99EgBWBP7JM-TMRlOh2jlkW5kv5qAAZmLvO+lbwvzw+BdUAAyvSFPoVHIoHcm1AxO0HNBgPToHPNZIFB0oAADANB1dQcRN-5EHi9GlW3QbmSWSIAIhU7lps4vnZ7woAeiMgA)