# How should one avoid excessively deep type instantiation when attemping to create recursive structures in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, recursion, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

Below is a simple example of a validate function that takes a "schema" and "source" value. I'm attempting to validate that "source" meets the requirements of "schema".

```js
// TypeScript v4.9.4

type SchemaMeta = { type: SchemaAll, extra?: boolean };
type Schema1 = 1;
type Schema2 = 2;

type SchemaAll = Schema1 | Schema2 | SchemaMeta;

type Source<Schema extends SchemaAll> = (
    Schema extends Schema1 ? "String Option #1" :
    Schema extends Schema2 ? "String Option #2" :
    Schema extends SchemaMeta ? Source<Schema["type"]> :
    never
);

function validate<Schema extends SchemaAll>(schema: Schema, source: Source<Schema>): void {
    // Incorrect
    // error TS2589: Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.
    source;
}

// Correct
validate({ type: 1 }, "String Option #1");

// Correct
validate({ type: { type: 2, extra: false } }, "String Option #2");

// Correct
// Argument of type '"String Option #1"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"String Option #2"'.
validate(2, "String Option #1");
```

In this stripped down example, If "schema" is 1, then "source" will be enforced to be "String Option #1". If it's 2, then "source" should be "String Option #2". However, it may also be a "SchemaMeta" object, which has a "type" field with the self-referencing type "SchemaAll".

I believe my annotations are logically correct, however I'm misunderstanding how TypeScript will interpret them. Once I use "source" in the body of the "validate" function, the code will no longer transpile with error TS2589, "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite".

How should I avoid excessively deep type instantiation when attemping to create recursive structures? (TypeScript v4.9.4)

Comment: [Credits to jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74408289/18244921): https://tsplay.dev/NB4LVW