# Typescript types - Now resolve "Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)"

Tags: typescript, typescript-types

I'm
playing with Typescript Types, and **I'm hit an error that I can't resolve and also not fully understand**.

#### Error

The error is the one mentioned on the title: `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite`.

I've read some material:

1. [recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#recursive-conditional-types)
2. [tail recursion elimination on conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types)

but I'm not able to resolve it for my specific case.

#### Code

Here my (simplified) code, that you can also view on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gdhAMhAtgezgBQDYFcDOAymihAIJhjYT4A8AkgHKYCqAKlBAB7ARwAm+KHFwoARhABOAPigBeKAG0oAckA8G4Gl9lQBooAOgMBhSRACGvAKLVScYHSas2u9YDl9ldIC6UAPTfaAWn8oNnBoAEs4fGBTWzDzMIwoMKFuAGMafDCANwhsECh+CAgwKBj+KDA0fEyxPKS4ADMIsN49AAoAJgBWAA4ATgBKACgR0EgoYzNLaz47Bk4ePkFhUQlJXQsF3gEhKMkIgHNdMi2l3eB9uAPFDzkb2QUh+lOdqDJFACJqK+AACw+vAB+N5QABcExM5ggVlQs3sG10igMejIGw80gA3CMhmNoKZkOg4GQBGxfiZyJRqEIFPAkKgMDgCMRSBQqDRaABmTFDXxQPkAPUBo1CpQJGGJ-DYAHc0KyqfJYAgxVg8EQSBS2XQOtzeQKhUA)

```
type OneLemonPlusSomeApples<INPUT extends number> = [ '', ...CreateElements<INPUT, ''>] //<-- Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.(2589)


type CreateElements<I extends number, E extends string, A extends string[]=[]> = 
I extends A["length"] ? A : CreateElements<I, E, [...A, E]>;


type aLemonAndThreeApples = OneLemonPlusSomeApples<3>;
//   ^?

type aLemonAndTwoApples = OneLemonPlusSomeApples<2>;
//   ^?
```

Why I'm getting the error when I'm using the spread operator (`...`)?

#### Note

As you might notice I'm using the tuple `A` as an accumulator and a way of keeping track of the iteration.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Something I picked up [from jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74408289/18244921), disabling distribution in conditionals [seems to work](https://tsplay.dev/W4JnAN) sometimes.